# Removing duplicate records in a dataframe based on the values of a list column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, distinct, tidyverse

I have a dataframe which contains duplicate values in a list column and I want to keep only the first appearence of each unique value.

Let's say I have the following tibble:

```r
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1,  tibble(a = 1:2, b = 2:3),
  2,  tibble(a = 1:2, b = 2:3),
  3,  tibble(a = 0:1, b = 0:1)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y               
#>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     2 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 3     3 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

The desired outcome is:

```r
desired_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x y               
#>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     3 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

Wasn't `y` a list column I'd be able to use `distinct(df, y, .keep_all = TRUE)`, but the fuction doesn't support list columns properly, as shown:

```r
distinct(df, y, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> Warning: distinct() does not fully support columns of type `list`.
#> List elements are compared by reference, see ?distinct for details.
#> This affects the following columns:
#> - `y`
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y               
#>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     2 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 3     3 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

Is there any "clean" way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I hope my solution is a clean option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `filter` with `duplicated`

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
    filter(!duplicated(y))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized that this approach, even though it works in the case I posted, doesn't work in some other more "complex" cases. For example, if I have the following dataframe ```df <- tribble(~x, ~y, 1,  tibble(a = 1:2, b = 2:3), 2,  tibble(a = c(1, 3), b = 2:3), 3,  tibble(a = 0:1, b = 0:1))``` my desired output would be a dataframe identical to `df`, since no nested dataframes are duplicate, but all of the proposed solutions remove the first row of the dataframe in the second row, because it's the same as the first dataframe's first row.

Comment: @dhersz WIth that new dataset, I get two 2 rows for the 'x', 1 row iin 'y' for 2 and 2 for 3.  Not sure what you expected

Comment: @dhersz in your own solutioin, it is not removing any rows

Comment: I might have expressed myself poorly. What I want is to remove duplicate nested dataframes, not the rows within these dataframes. So in the original tibble, for example, removing the whole second row would do it. In the case of the dataframe I made in my previous comment, there would be no need to remove any rows because all dataframes in the list column are unique.

Comment: @dhersz so, it is basically duplicates within each tibble and not across?

Comment: @dhersz I updatd the post.  It is working for both of your datasets

Comment: actually, duplicate tibbles. not within neither across

Comment: @dhersz yes, the update works for that i.e. `df %>%
    filter(!duplicated(y))`

Answer (score 1):

I have come to an answer, but I think it's quite "wordy" (and I suspect it might be slow as well):

```r
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(unique_list_id = match(y, unique(y))) %>% 
  group_by(unique_list_id) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-unique_list_id)

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x y               
#>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     3 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```